# Dynamic path to CSS & Javascript folders

Tags: php, path

In a php project I have created a template for Website Header & included a javascript & css menu in it.

Paths for the js & css files for menu are referenced in Header Template so I do not need to include those in every page.

When I include the header template to content pages which are in different levels in folder hierachy, path to js & css file change & does not load. How to overcome this & reference js & css files in a dynamic way?

Comment: Are you using an MVC framework (e.g. CodeIgniter, Symfony, CakePHP, etc)?

Comment: @Blowski No im not using any framework. It's pure PHP.

Comment: Related: [Base URL in .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848428/base-url-in-htaccess)

Comment: OK, the relative path is probably the best way to go (as per @Quentin's answer).

Comment: Oops - just saw that you said that's not working. Can you give some more details about what's not working, please.

Comment: @Blowski When I change the css reference to "<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public_html/css/Default.css"></link>" css does not load...

Answer (score 1):

Use URIs relative to the server root.

i.e. which start with a `/` character.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change this by using absolute links in your header template. Just give them an *absolute URI* like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/path/to/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Absolute URIs will prevent that you need to deal with the resolving of relative URIs to the documents own *base URI*.

If you dislike to hard-encode the name of your site, you can make use of server variables (take a look into `$_SERVER`), resolve the base URI to the document of the request and adopt the path to the CSS/JS files on the fly.

I recommend to not hard-encode personally, however this is less trivial to implement and depends on server configuration, your site's layout and has security implications as well.