# Mod Rewrite Rule re-writing incorrectly

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

In my .htaccess file i have the following re-write rule

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]*)$ work.php?album=$1 [L]
```

I am reading all directories in root directoy and creating links like

code in PHP

```
$dir=glob('images/works/*');
$dir_listing=array();
foreach($dir as $list)  
{
if(is_dir($list))
$dir_listing[]= (basename($list));
}
foreach($dir_listing as $folders )  
echo"<a href='$folders' ><img src='Default-thumbnail-folder.jpg' /> </a>";
```

the problem is i have three folders under works directory *{alb,ban,bas}*

the first and last *{alb and bas}* work properly for my redirect rule *URL{siteName/works/bas}*

but the second {ban} creates a URL like *{siteName/works/ban/}* Notice the extra **"/"** is creating the problem, it seems for some folder names it is creating the problem, so please help me in creating a proper redirect rule

i want a link like

```
<a href="alb" >About</a> // to redirect to work.php?content=about
```

I also notice that if URL in browser is like work/alb/ CSS is not applied 
i tried

```
<link href="sample.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

and

```
<link href="css/sample.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

it does not work for URL like {works/about/} it works for {works/about}

Comment: What you ask about (which are multiple problems at once - but related) has been asked about earlier. You probably don't know what to search for. For the CSS problem I remember this question: [Base URL in .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6848428/367456) (I'm sure there are other, related questions as well, that's just one).

Comment: `RewriteRule ^([a-z\/]*)$ work.php?album=$1 [L]` this should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy!

Try to change your rewriterule to:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]*)/?$ work.php?album=$1 [L]
```

So that the "`/`" at the end may or may not be present, in both cases it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

to avoid rewriting css URI's use these rules

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

as for your other problem you can use a trim on the result url to make sure you never have a "/" at the end
`trim($url,'/');`