# How to properly create relative links

Tags: php

in my source code, this a button link like this:
[image]

then the web page's code is like this:
[image]

but when click the button, the url is:
http://localhost/personal/applications/mywebtest/install/?step=2

why "/personal/applications" is added in?

Comment: localhost/personal/application is your base path of the web.. first check your `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` and print this

Comment: Does your site have a `<base href="">` element?

Comment: $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']  value  is  /mywebtest/install/index.php   and  thers is no <base> tag

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Let me start with...

### How the `href` attribute works

Let's say, you are on a page `http://example.com/foo/bar.html` and you have a hyperlink there, it can be one of the three:

- `path/newpage.html` - this is a relative path (no slash in front), which means it will take you to `http://example.com/foo/path/newpage.html`
- `/path/newpage.html` - this is an absolute path (starts with a slash), which will take you to `http://example.com/path/newpage.html`
- `example.com/otherpage.html` - this is still a relative path (as in the first example), it will take you to `http://example.com/example.com/otherpage.html` *
  *this is because the browser don't know if you mean domain `example.com` or directory with a dot in it `example.com`, so it's a standard to treat it as a directory.*
- `http://example.com/path/newpage.html` - this is an absolute URL (it starts with a protocol) - the browser don't need to do any guessing here, can take you straight to `http://example.com/path/newpage.html`

*(this is assuming that the `base` is not set, please read rest of the answer or take a look at https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp)*

### Now the original answer

When you use `relative` links (links without domain name) in the `<a>` elements your browser needs a whole URL (with domain name) to fulfill such request when you click the link. So it takes the current protocol (`http`) and domain `localhost` and glues it with `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` which is

> The filename of the currently executing script, relative to the
>   document root. For instance, $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] in a script at the
>   address http://example.com/foo/bar.php would be /foo/bar.php.
>   (https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

So you can either create full urls for the href as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46359685/299774

```
href=<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/mywebtest/install"; ?>?step=2';"
```

But this can cause problems in case you want to save such HTML in the DB (for example it is a post in your blog) - then moving your app to a different domain would require changing contents in the DB and fill it with new domain.

So I would stick to relative values in `href`, you can accomplish that by setting `base` meta tag in your HTML: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6848509/299774

or by utilizing [mod_rewrite](https://www.google.pl/search?dcr=0&source=hp&q=php%20mod_rewrite&oq=php%20mod_rewrite&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l4.1313.3966.0.4085.16.15.0.0.0.0.147.1193.14j1.15.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..1.15.1192.0..0i10k1.0.os-k-ZrbQGM) or similar tool four your server, but it has been long since I was doing it + outside of scope of this question, but you can check popular frameworks (CakePHP, Laravel) how they do it.

(And they have to do it, because being able to move app between domains is a must: local testing, staging, production)

Comment: when i use:  href='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?step=2'
the url in web page is:  onclick="location.href='/mywebtest/install/index.php?step=2';" 
click it, the url is: http://localhost/personal/applications/mywebtest/install/?step=2

when i use:  href='<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/mywebtest/install"; ?>?step=2'
the url in web page is:  onclick="location.href='localhost/mywebtest/install?step=2';"
click it, the url is:  http://localhost/mywebtest/install/localhost/mywebtest/install?step=2  

it's oddly, i am a beginner, i can't understand how it works really.

Comment: to make it an absolute url - you need to have protocol (http:// or https://) as well.

Answer (score -1):

That's because `PHP_SELF` returns the path on disk to the current file. PHP itself is unaware of where/how the page is served. You will have to find another variable/strategy for your link. Also, if you really want to link to the same page, you could just use `?step=2`.

Answer (score -1):

you can use of  **$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']**

```
         <input type="button" name="step" value="Continue to step 2 of 3"
onClick="location.href = '<?php echo (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])?"https" : "http")."://". $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/mywebtest/install/"; ?>?step=2';"/>
```

Comment: when i modify it like this : $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/mywebtest/install" 
,   the url changes to     http://localhost/mywebtest/install/localhost/mywebtest/install?step=2

Comment: you mean i must use an absolute path? how can i use  a relative path? change some apache config file?

Comment: no you don't need change Apache config file.You just have to specify your target URL address.**/mywebtest/install/**.